# Replace mysql user defined variable

Tags: mysql

I have a query which works great given that the result is only one number, but now I need to allow for multiple rows to be returned and the query cannot handle that because it uses a user define variable... here is original procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `MapRank`(pTankID bigint,pMapID int, pColor int(2))
BEGIN
SET @RankNumber:=0; 
select RankNumber 
from 
(select 
    TankID,
    @RankNumber:=@RankNumber+1 as RankNumber,
    MapID,
    Color 
 from MAPDATA WHERE MapID = pMapID order by Rank DESC, TotalPP DESC) Query1 where TankID = pTankID AND COLOR = pColor ;
END
```

this returns a single number, essentially counting the number of records down it is, giving me the "row" location.

now I need to change it to give me all rows with out the where for mapid and color, so that I can see all ranks for all mapid/color combo

this is what I have that currently does not work

```
SET @RankNumber:=0;
select 
    RankNumber,MapID,COlor
from
    (select 
        TankID,
            @RankNumber:=@RankNumber + 1 as RankNumber,
            MapID,
            Color
    from
        MAPDATA

    order by TotalPP DESC) Query1
where
    TankID = 18209 ORDER BY RankNumber
```

the yielding query result looks as such:

```
1062    3   1
3544    3   0
6717    17  1
6752    17  3
7453    3   2
7860    17  0
7984    17  2
9220    3   3
```

if I run manually lets say, map id 3 and color 3 which says rank number is 9220 with the FIRST query I get this

```
6022
```

I need this to be able to be done possibly from multiple MySQL connections so ideally done without use of a temporary variable since its possible another person may come in and use that... any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

After digging and messing more I have found the solution to be to set the variable back to zero from within the outer select.. and since user defined variable are connection level and I utilize pooling we should never have an issue.

```
SET @RankNumber:=0;
select 
    RankNumber,MapID,COlor, @RankNumber:=0
from
    (select 
        TankID,
            @RankNumber:=@RankNumber + 1 as RankNumber,
            MapID,
            Color
    from
        MAPDATA

    order by MapID, Rank DESC, TotalPP DESC ) Query1
where
    TankID = pTankID ORDER BY RankNumber;
```